# SharePoint 2013 Central Admin 500 After March 2019 CU

Tags: sharepoint

After installing March 2019 CU on SharePoint 2013 I had a disconnect from SQL server.
Fixed the SQL Issue and had to leave the farm and connect again.
All the web applications are working fine except "Central Admin" 
when trying to open Central Admin, the browser shows HTTP error 500.
I tried all the solutions listed [here](http://itfreesupport.com/2014/08/common-troubleshooting-step-sharepoint-web-site-and-central-admin-500-internal-server-error/) nothing helped.

Is there a way to create a new central admin without losing the existing services?

Comment: March 2019 CU for SharePoint 2013 or Windows 10 or SQL Server?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: If you uninstall the cumulative update does it become operational?

Comment: Never Uninstall CU. how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
New-SPCentralAdministration -WindowsAuthProvider NTLM -Port 8080
```

and it did the trick.
SharePoint creates a new web application that had all the necessary content.